# Winforms DataGridView in VirtualMode when to call AutoResizeColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autoresize, virtualmode

I have implemented a `DataGridView` on my form and successfully implemented `VirtualMode`.  This retrieves cell data from a local cache and all appears to be working correctly when populating the grid/paging etc.  I handle the `DataGridView.CellValueNeeded` event to populate the cells.

On the DataGridView, I have the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property set to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells`.  I have noticed that in using VirtualMode the DataGridView does not appear to respect the AutoSizeColumnsMode after populating the cells.  I have examined [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt.aspx) but not found a solution.

What I would ultimately like to do is to not rely on the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property, but rather call the `.AutoResizeColumn()` method *somewhere* to resize, so I initially autosize the column, but then allow the user to resize.

I have tried the following with limited or no success:

1. Set `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `.None`.  Then in my
   `.CellValueNeeded` handler

   ```
   private void dataGridView_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
   {
       // ... Get cell value from cache
      dataGridView.AutoResizeColumn(e.ColumnIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells);
    }
   ```

   This throws a `StackOverFlowException` presumably because it
   repeatedly raises `.CellValueNeeded`.
2. Tried exactly the same thing except in the `.CellFormatting`
       event handler.  Got the same  `StackOverFlowException`.
3. Tried with and without `DataGridView.SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout`:

   ```
   private void dataGridView_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
   {
       // ... Get cell value from cache
      dataGridView.CellValueNeeded -= dataGridView_CellValueNeeded;
      dataGridView.AutoResizeColumn(e.ColumnIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells);
      dataGridView.CellValueNeeded += dataGridView_CellValueNeeded;
   }
   ```

   This gives all blank cells, so no use.
4. This one actually somewhat works, for a reason I don't understand:

   ```
   private void dataGridView_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
   {
       // ... Get cell value from cache
       dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
   }
   ```

   It resizes the columns correctly, but it seems odd to have to repeatedly call it on every cell value needed.  Also, I cannot immediately set it to .None right after or it will `StackOverFlowException` again.  Thus, I cannot allow user to resize columns.
5. Calling `.UpdateCellValue()` as mentioned in the article from my `.CellValueNeeded` handler throws `StackOverFlowException` as well.

So is it possible to call `.AutoResizeColumn()` somewhere where it won't raise `.CellValueNeeded` until it overflows?  Since #4 seems to have the ability to perform the autosize function it seems as though I could manually call it from somewhere as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be the solution, although I am still interested in hearing what others have to say.

I continued to look at some of the other events raised by the `DataGridView` and found the `.RowPostPaint` event.  I created the following handler:

```
private void dataGridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns) //So not to run unnecessarily
    {
        return;
    }
    var lastIndex = dataGridView.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed);
    if (e.RowIndex == lastIndex) //Only do on the last displayed row
    {
        dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
        dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;  // User has control from here on
    }
}
```

This accomplishes the autosizing of the columns upon the initial data-load, then allows the user to re-size from there.  It only does this once, so way better than on every cell value needed.  I must set `dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false` prior to initial data loading.

This seems to fit the bill.  The user will see nicely fit columns upon initial load and can tweak from there, and most of my data is comparable length from row to row, so should not truncate or waste space after that in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you state that you are interested in what others have to say, I've put together a slightly different approach for how to use automatic column resizing with a virtual data grid.

The initial AutoResizeColumns call is placed after the Shown event so that the form and child components are initialized and displayed. Also, by wiring the DataGridView Scroll event for resizing, rather than RowPostPaint, this should be ever so slightly more efficient because this event fires less frequently, and I think it follows along nicely with the MSDN reference you cite:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewTest
{
    public partial class DataGridViewForm : Form
    {
        private List<string> dataSource;

        public DataGridViewForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Enable VirtualMode for dataGridView1
            dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;

            // Wire CellValueNeeded event handler
            dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded;

            // Wire Scroll event handler
            dataGridView1.Scroll += DataGridView1_Scroll;

            // Wire form Shown event handler
            this.Shown += DataGridViewForm_Shown;
        }

        private void DataGridViewForm_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Populate dataGridView1 here to avoid perception of a long form startup time
            populateDataGridView();

            // Resize columns after the form is initialized and displayed on screen,
            // otherwise calling this method won't actually have an effect on column sizes
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the triggering cell's value to the corresponding value from dataSource
            e.Value = dataSource[e.RowIndex];
        }

        private void DataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            // Resize columns again, but only if a vertical scroll just happened
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
            {
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
            }
        }

        private void populateDataGridView()
        {
            fetchIntoDataSource();

            associateDataSourceToDataGridView();
        }

        private void fetchIntoDataSource()
        {
            dataSource = new List<string>();

            // Insert a test string into dataSource many times
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                dataSource.Add("test string");
            }
        }

        private void associateDataSourceToDataGridView()
        {
            // Synchronize dataGridView1.RowCount to dataSource.Count
            // This is necessary for the CellValueNeeded event to fire
            dataGridView1.RowCount = dataSource.Count;
        }
    }
}
```